# How can I find the records which has last character "A" in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have huge `JSON` file in `notepad++`. One my field is `product`. I want to find out all the products which has character `A` in last in Value.

This is my data

```
{
    "ID": 689,
    "product": "GIPA",
    "JobID": 66349,
    "FriendlyName": "Android",
},
{
    "ID": 689,
    "product": "TKNA",
    "JobID": 66350,
    "FriendlyName": "Android",
},
{
    "ID": 689,
    "product": "TNRG",
    "JobID": 66351,
    "FriendlyName": "Android",
},
{
    "ID": 689,
    "product": "GAJT",
    "JobID": 66352,
    "FriendlyName": " Android",
},
```

I have tried two way but those are not working

```
"product": "^[a-z|A-Z|0-9]+[^A]\s?I{1}$"
```

And

```
"product": ".*(\A)$"
```

How can I find first two records?

Comment: Do you mean you want to match all `product` lines where the value does not end with `A`? `"product": "[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?<!A)"`? Could you please add this clarification to the question body? It is not clear why you tried `[a-z|A-Z|0-9]+[^A]\s?I`. Why `[^A]`, `\s?` and `I`?

Comment: You see, I ask because the pattern you tried contradicts what you wrote before. Then `"product": "[a-zA-Z0-9]*A"`? `"product": "[^"]*A"`? What is the final result you need, just find the match? Not replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the major issues with your regexps:

- `"product": "^[a-z|A-Z|0-9]+[^A]\s?I{1}$"` contains `^` inside the pattern and thus it will never match as there is no start of string in the middle of it, where there is no pattern matching a line break before `^`
- `[a-z|A-Z]` matches letters AND also `|`, do not use `|` in character classes if you do not mean to match a literal `|` char (it loses its "alternation" meaning in between `[...]`
- `[^A]` matches any char but `A`
- `{1}` is always redundant, remove it. All patterns inside an expression are tried once by default.
- `"product": ".*(\A)$"` contains `\A`, start of string anchor, which also invalidates the pattern, it will no longer match any string

You can use

```
"product": "[^"]*A"
```

It matches

- `"product": "` - a literal string
- `[^"]*` - 0 or more chars other than `"`
- `A"` - `A"` string.